# Sidekiq testing perform_in

Tags: ruby, rspec, sidekiq, rspec-sidekiq

I wonder if there's anyway to test whether sidekiq properly executes a job in X seconds(or enqueues a job to be performed in X seconds), as specified in a `perform_in` call.

As far as I can tell, the docs don't allude to any mode that allows this. In `fake` mode, it seems the job is directly added to the queue and executed immediately at the `drain` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in `fake` mode, you can access the your Workers jobs with `MyWorker.jobs`.

If you scheduled your jobs with `perform_in` they should have a field `at` giving you the execution time (as float).
I wrote a rspec test along the line of

```
subject { MyWorker.jobs.first }    
it 'is scheduled in 1 minute' do
  span = subject['at'] - Time.now.to_f
  expect(span.round).to eq 60
end
```

I hope that helps!