# Write a feature Test using capybara when using sidekiq `perform_in` method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, sidekiq

Most stuff I can find related is about testing that the background job is scheduled like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31125338/sidekiq-testing-perform-in) question.

However, I need to write a feature test that actually waits for the execution of the background job, so let's say:

```
BatchWorker.perform_in(30.minutes)
```

I will need to write a feature test that makes some assertions based on the results of this job that will execute in 30 minutes. How to do that?

**UPDATE**

Just to clarify... I don't need to test if the job is enqueued, for example with rspec-sidekiq gem you can do something like

```
Awesomejob.perform_in 30.minutes, 'Awesome', true
# test with...
expect(AwesomeJob).to have_enqueued_sidekiq_job('Awesome', true).in(30.minutes)
```

This is not what I need... I need to make an assertion on the page with capybara after the execution of the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't actually want to wait the 30 minutes during your test, and instead want to execute the job immediately (otherwise you just sleep for 30 minutes - but really doesn't gain you anything).  The Sidekiq adapter has a number of methods to help with this such as `Sidekiq::Testing.fake!` and `Sidekiq::Testing.inline!`.  In your case it sounds like for this test you'd want to use `inline!` in order to have the jobs executed immediately.

```
require "sidekiq/testing"
Sidekiq::Testing.inline!
```

If you used `fake!` then you'd need to call `drain_all` in order to have your enqueued jobs be executed.  You can read more about this at https://sloboda-studio.com/blog/testing-sidekiq-jobs/ or in the sidekiq  wiki and code at https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing and  https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/testing.rb

Comment: Thanks! it worked! it seems the easiest is adding `Sidekiq::Testing.inline!` to a `before` block in the spec file.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout [rspec-sidekiq](https://github.com/philostler/rspec-sidekiq)

```
Awesomejob.perform_in 30.minutes, 'Awesome', true
# test with...
expect(AwesomeJob).to have_enqueued_sidekiq_job('Awesome', true).in(30.minutes)
```

Comment: But this is testing if the job is enqueued, this is not what Im looking for. I need to check something in the page with capybara after the execution of the job...